# User inputted integer using while statement

Tags: python

Ok need to understand why my code is not working.
At the moment it's getting stuck in a infinite loop of asking the user for a pin after a wrong pin is inputted.

I believe I'm screwing up the while statement somehow.

```
def inputValidator():
    userInput = requestInteger("Please input a PIN between 1 - 1000")
    while 1 > userInput > 1000 : 
        requestInteger("Your PIN is not within 1 - 1000, please try again")
    print("Thanks! your new PIN is " + str(userInput))
```

thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def inputValidator():
    userInput = requestInteger("Please input a PIN between 1 - 1000")
    while userInput<1 or userInput>1000:
        userInput = requestInteger("Your PIN is not within 1 - 1000, please try again")
    print("Thanks! your new PIN is " + str(userInput))
```

You'll want a new input from your user if `userInput` is smaller than 1 or bigger than 1000 - and like @Polina F. said - you didn't assign a new value to `userInput` inside the while loop. This is why it loops for ever.

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign nothing in the while loop. userInput  never gets updated - hence you can't exit the loop

Answer (score 1):

you aren't assigning requestInteger to userInput

```
while 1 > userInput > 1000 : 
  userInput =requestInteger("Your PIN is not within 1 - 1000, please try again")
```